# Android does not recognise ids from an included file

Tags: android, xml, include

I'm making an Android application where I need to include a header and footer. To make the xml creation easier, I include header and footer from another xml.

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<include layout="@layout/header" />
<!-- FOOTER --> 
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Problem is that I want to use android:layout_below and android:layout_above to guarantee that content is on the middle of both elements, but when I try to call the id of those elements:

```
android:layout_below="@id/header"
android:layout_above="@id/footer"
```

they are not recognised:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/footer').

Instead, in the preview it works. I would like to know what's the problem or if there are another option to be ensure that content is in his place.

Thank you!

P.S.:Here's the header code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:background="@color/color_cabecera"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/logo100x80" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_abridores"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abridores_guardados" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_consejos"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/consejos_guardados" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:text="@string/app_name"     
    android:textSize="20sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it should be `@+id/header`

Comment: it is because your include tag has no id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because your `include` tag has no id. I suppose you have  `android:id="@+id/header"` declared into `header.xml`, but you can't use it as anchor id in your `RelativeLayout`

```
  <include layout="@layout/header" 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   />
```

Comment: It seems that it works without width and height parameters. With those parameters, there's an null pointer exception. Instead, it's enough help to continue. Thank you very much!